# How does one solve a 2D relative velocity problem given 3 angles and 1 magnitude?

Tags: velocity, vectors, relative-motion

Most of it is the title. To be a bit more clear, I am asking about a problem involving two traveling objects. The question gives you the angle of motion of both objects relative to the earth, and the angle of motion of object 1 relative to object 2. It also gives the magnitude of the velocity of object 1 relative to earth. I want to find the magnitude of object 2's velocity, then I can solve the rest from there. How would I go about this?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to find out.

Comment: Oh whoops. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a diagram, showing the two objects at two different time points - one, when they are both at the same point (the intersection of the two paths), the other one second later. This should allow you to construct the "angle of 1 relative to 2" as a function of the unknown velocity $v_2$. But since the angle is given you can then solve for $v_2$.